# How to change C:\ to other disk(D:\ or USB)

Tags: cmd

So when i open the cmd the path is:

```
C:\Users\Admin
```

How to change it to

```
D:\****\*****
```

or

```
USB:\****\****
```

Comment: How do you *open the cmd*?

Comment: go to start and search cmd

Comment: So [edit] your question to provide that information, instead of burying it in comments.

Comment: @L.Chan Are you trying to change the default directory it opens in, or just navigate to a different path?

Comment: See [Add the Command Prompt to the Windows Explorer Right-Click Menu](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/add-the-command-prompt-to-the-windows-explorer-right-click-menu/). But I suggest to use `cd /D %1` instead of just `cd %1` to work for any drive with a drive letter.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way for you to do this for you is; open Windows Explorer.

1. Type the following in the address bar: `%windir%\system32`.
2. Then find the file called `cmd.exe`.
3. Right click on the file, then Pin it to the taskbar; or Pin it to the start menu, or save it as a shortcut to your desktop.
4. Find the shortcut you just made.  Right click on that file, and choose properties.
5. Under the `Shortcut` tab in the dialog, goto the text input that says `Start In`.  Enter the directory you want it to start in in that field.  Click OK.
6. Use the `Cmd` shortcut you just made, and you will start in that directory.

*Note*:  If you want to use USB:, you will need to look into `My Computer` and figure out what drive letter has been assigned to the USB device and choose that letter for the path.

*Note*:  All of this is really trivial, because from the `cmd prompt` you can type `D:\` to navigate to D drive or `pushd D:\***\***` to navigate to a folder on the D drive.